# Install Package without dependencies from AUR in Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, manjaro, pacman, aur

I'm trying to install CamlImages(http://gallium.inria.fr/camlimages/), I can't seem to get it to work by building it myself so I am trying to get it from the AUR.

My problem is, it has `omake` listed as a dependecy. The `omake` package in AUR does not work for Manjaro, so I installed `omake` manually. This does not solve things though, because when I try to build CamlImages with `pamac`, it still tries to install `omake` (which obviously fails).

Note: I have no experience with OCaml, I just need CamlImages to get this to work: http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/whizzytex.html

Answer (score 3):

AUR works with `PKGBUILD` files, which are the "recipes" for building a package. So you can simply remove `omake` from the `PKGBUILD`. You can get this file from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/camlimages/ but you can also use `yay`(an AUR helper).

The following steps should work:

1. Download `PKGBUILD` with `yay -G camlimages`
2. In the `PKGBUILD` file, remove `omake` from `makedepends`
3. Install package with `makepkg -si`

[source](https://github.com/Jguer/yay/issues/750#issuecomment-427270953)

**NB:** the `camlimages` on AUR was last updated in 2015, so it might not be up-to-date. However, the `PKGBUILD` may give you some hints on how to build a new version.